# How to automate the manual UI of silverlight application using SilverlightTest framework or STATLIGHT

Tags: c#, automated-tests, silverlight-5.0, silverlight-toolkit, statlight

Currently our instrument product is totally manual intervention which is silverlight UI app.
Due to the client requirement the UI needs to be automate by writing automated UI testcases in C#.NET in  Visual Studio IDE on SL application which reduces the manual intervention.

Please help me how to begin or start in understanding and writing good Automated UI testcases/testmethods for the SL UI using **SilverlightTest framework/STATLIGHT**(`Except CodedUI`). Are there any good books/references/links available to explore better? Do i need to install any tools/toolkit  to work with Silverlight UI with STATLIGHT for writing  automated testcases.

Answer (score 1):

For example you can use [Microsoft Coded UI Tests](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286726.aspx). Disadvantage is that you need at least Visual Studio (2012) Premium. Works fine in your projects.

Comment: Ok, thats import new point ;-). But nevertheless if you stack with SilverlightTest framework/STATLIGHT consider CUIT.